# Android - add icon in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-studio

I need to add an icon at the top right of the menu in the `ActionBar` when an item is selected from the `NavigationDrawer` menu.

So I have create a new file called for example '`blog`' that extends `Fragment` and I have write in it the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method that should manage the menu action bar right?

This is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Blog extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.blog, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.blog_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Android studio write in red this line of code:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
```

so I think that it is wrong but I do not understand what is the problem...any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To control your menu inside a `Fragment`, you need to call this method:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

inside `onCreateView` method. Then, you need the `MenuInflater` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    MenuItem itemBlog = menu.add(Menu.NONE, // Group ID
                                 R.id.blog_item, // Item ID
                                 1, // Order
                                 R.string.blog_item); // Title
    itemBlog.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM); // ShowAsAction
    itemBlog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_blog); // Icon
    // add your item before calling the super method
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

I don't know if this is the case, however if you use the `AppCompat` library, you should do as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    MenuItem itemBlog = menu.add(Menu.NONE, // Group ID
                                 R.id.action_blog, // Item ID
                                 101, // Order
                                 "Blog"); // Title
    // To showAsAction attribute, use MenuItemCompat (set to always)
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(itemBlog, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    itemBlog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_blog);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

This works well.

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi I've just tried this snippnet, it works.. What are you currently using *AppCompat*, *ABSherlock* or nothing for your ActionBar?

Comment: I have started a new project and it works, maybe I have removed something in the previous project, thanks!